# How to sort names by their scores from rolling dice

Tags: python

I'm working on a program that generates three different integers and assigns them to individual values so that It can be decided to goes first, second, and third.  In this case, I'm assuming three different players, each one rolls a "ten-sided die".  The highest should get the first turn, second highest should go second, third should go last.  Everything seems to be rolling okay, but now that I have my values I can't figure out how to arrange them so that I can start having the players take turns playing.  I would appreciate any input.

Here is the code I've put together so far:

```
import sys
import os
import random
import time

os.system('clear')
print ('Welcome!  Please type Player 1\'s name!: ')
playerOne = input()
print ('Okay!  Please type Player 2\'s name!: ')
playerTwo = input()
print ('Fantastic!  Finally, please type Player 3\'s name!: ')
playerThree = input()
os.system('clear')
print()
time.sleep(2)

def startFightRoll():
    playerOneRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Okay, let\'s roll a ten-sided die to see who gets to go first!')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerOne + ' rolls ' + str(playerOneRoll))
    print()
    print()
    playerTwoRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerTwo + ' rolls ' + str(playerTwoRoll))
    print()
    print()
    playerThreeRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerThree + ' rolls ' + str(playerThreeRoll))

startFightRoll()
```

In response to threads below;

Okay, so I'm new at this so please forgive my code - it's not efficient and I'm still getting used to things. I've added some parts to it to address 1) player entering nothing in the name field, and 2) ties being generated in the dice roll. I've also created a list of the dice rolls in descending order, but now I need to find a way to assocate the rolls back to the user who generated it. Any pointers on how to do this properly is deeply appreciated;

```
import sys
import os
import random
import time

os.system('clear')


def playerOneName():
    global playerOne
    playerOne = input()
    if len(playerOne) < 1:
        print('Please enter your name, Player 1!')
        playerOneName()

def playerTwoName():
    global playerTwo
    playerTwo = input()
    if len(playerTwo) < 1:
        print('Please enter your name, Player 2!')
        playerTwoName()

def playerThreeName():
    global playerThree
    playerThree = input()
    if len(playerThree) < 1:
        print('Please enter your name, Player 3!')
        playerThreeName()

os.system('clear')
print()
time.sleep(2)
def startFightRoll():
    global playerOneRoll
    global playerTwoRoll
    global playerThreeRoll
    playerOneRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Okay, let\'s roll a ten-sided die to see who gets to go first!')
    print()
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerOne + ' rolls ' + str(playerOneRoll))
    print()
    print()
    playerTwoRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerTwo + ' rolls ' + str(playerTwoRoll))
    print()
    print()
    playerThreeRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    time.sleep(2)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerThree + ' rolls ' + str(playerThreeRoll))
    if playerOneRoll == playerTwoRoll:
        print ('There\'s a tie, rolling again!')
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system('clear')
        startFightRoll()
    if playerOneRoll == playerThreeRoll:
        print ('There\'s a tie, rolling again!')
        time.sleep(3)
        os.system('clear')
        startFightRoll()
    if playerTwoRoll == playerThreeRoll:
        print ('There\'s a tie, rolling again!')
        os.system('clear')
        time.sleep(3)
        startFightRoll()    

    O = [playerOneRoll, playerTwoRoll, playerThreeRoll]
    O = sorted(O, reverse = True)
    print (O)

print ('Welcome!  Please type Player 1\'s name!: ')
playerOneName()
print ('Okay!  Please type Player 2\'s name!: ')
playerTwoName()
print ('Fantastic!  Finally, please type Player 3\'s name!: ')
playerThreeName()
os.system('clear')
startFightRoll()
```

Comment: There is an obvious flaw here in that you are doing what is known as copy-paste programming - where you are doing the same thing twice, you shouldn't be copying a block of code to do it again, you should be organizing your data into a data structure and then looping over it to do the same action for each piece, or writing functions to allow you to do the same task in different situations. Here your player names and rolls could be in a dictionary, for example.

Comment: @Kimomaru We understand that you are new to this, but both Lattyware and myself have pointed out to you that copying/pasting code isn't a good idea. Also, what's was wrong with my answer's way of determining if there were duplicate number rolls? Lastly, my answer returns the names of the players in descending order, is there a reason you need to know what numbers they initially rolled?

Answer (score 2):

Like Lattyware mentioned, you are repeating some of your code. Not only does it makes it too busy to read, but it presents the opportunity of messing up your logic (if you forget to change a variable after pasting). Therefore it's a good practice to put repeating code into a function.

Regarding your code, I took into account if two players roll the same number. In this case, the program will roll again until a new number is rolled.

```
import os
import random
import time

os.system('clear')
print ('Welcome!  Please type Player 1\'s name!: ')
playerOne = input()
print ('Okay!  Please type Player 2\'s name!: ')
playerTwo = input()
print ('Fantastic!  Finally, please type Player 3\'s name!: ')
playerThree = input()
os.system('clear')
print()
time.sleep(2)


def initialRoll(player):
    """Roll the dice for the given player"""

    playerRoll = random.randint(1, 10)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (player + ' rolls ' + str(playerRoll))
    print()
    return playerRoll


def startFightRoll():
    """Determine the order of the players."""

    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Okay, let\'s roll a ten-sided die to see who gets to go first!')
    print()

    // Temporarily store the rolls. The key is the roll number and the value is the
    // player who rolled it
    order = {}
    for player in [playerOne, playerTwo, playerThree]:
        playerRoll = initialRoll(player)

        # Let's make sure that two players didn't roll the same number, if they did
        # then let's roll a new number
        while playerRoll in order:
            print ('OH No! That number has already been rolled. Let\'s roll again')
            playerRoll = initialRoll(player)

        order[playerRoll] = player
        time.sleep(2)

    # Sort the keys (which are the numbers rolled), then create a new list with order
    # of who should go first
    return [order[roll] for roll in sorted(order.keys(), reverse=True)]

rollOrder = startFightRoll()
print ('The order of the players are: ' + ', '.join(rollOrder))
```

Comment: This answer is more complete than mine! +1

Answer (score 0):

Add your values to a list (say the list is `x`):

```
x = sorted(x)
```

You want to use a dictionary.

Add each of the player names and their random rolls to a dictionary:

```
players = {'player1': randint(1, 10), 'player2': randint(1, 10), 'player3': randint(1, 10)}
```

However, for your purposes, you want the opposite of this dictionary (the roll then the player name) because you want to iterate through the rolls. This will mess up if any of the rolls are the same, so you could create a larger range (`randint(1, 1000)`, for example):

```
players = {randint(1, 1000): 'player1', randint(1, 1000): 'player2', randint(1, 1000): 'player3'}
rolls = sorted(players.keys())
player_sequence = [players[n] for n in rolls]
```

Comment: @Joran It doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @askewchan He asked how to sort values, which `sorted(x)` accomplishes.

Comment: Forgive the OP the vague title, or help by editing it.  Don't answer the simplest interpretation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one possible alternative, creating a dictionary and sorting its keys (it's a bit odd, I admit). Notice the three "duplicated" blocks, so please take it one step further by implementing Lattyware's comment's suggestion of looping over each player.

```
import sys
import os
import random
import time

os.system('clear')
print ('Welcome!  Please type Player 1\'s name!: ')
playerOne = raw_input()
print ('Okay!  Please type Player 2\'s name!: ')
playerTwo = raw_input()
print ('Fantastic!  Finally, please type Player 3\'s name!: ')
playerThree = raw_input()
os.system('clear')
print()
time.sleep(2)
def startFightRoll():
    time.sleep(.5)
    print('Okay, let\'s roll a ten-sided die to see who gets to go first!')
    print

    rolls = {}

    playerOneRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    rolls[playerOneRoll] = 'Player One'
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerOne + ' rolls ' + str(playerOneRoll))
    print
    print

    playerTwoRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    rolls[playerTwoRoll] = 'Player Two'
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerTwo + ' rolls ' + str(playerTwoRoll))
    print
    print

    playerThreeRoll = random.randint(1,10)
    rolls[playerThreeRoll] = "Player Three"
    time.sleep(1)
    print ('<Ten-sided dice roll> ')
    print ('---------------------------------')
    print (playerThree + ' rolls ' + str(playerThreeRoll))
    print
    print

    print "The winner is %s" % rolls[max(rolls.keys())]


startFightRoll()
```

Comment: Should use `playerOne` etc as the keys, since it asks for their names already. Their roll should be the value, and sort the dict by the values.

Comment: @askewchan I implemented it "reversed" because I sort the results, and after that I look up who has this result. Since keys are used for lookup, I've chosen to use result as key (that is what I know after sorting), and user name as (looked-up) value.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. I edited your answer to use the input player names as the value.

Comment: This only gives the user who rolled the highest number. The OP wants to know the order of the players.

Comment: @CarlosV I believe the modifications shown are enought for the OP to figure out the simple extra modifications needed for him to achieve what he wants.